# Is there any way we can call a handler when user clicks admob ads ?

Tags: android, admob

I would like to log something each time user clicks an ad in my app. Does Admob SDK has any such handlers ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are looking for `AdListener.onAdOpened()`.
See 
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener